# Add Without to Likeness for unknown amount of properties dynamically

Tags: c#, unit-testing, linq-to-objects, autofixture

With the following function Likeness is created for each item of a generic list:

```
private static IEnumerable<Likeness<T, T>> CreateLikenessOfListItems<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> list) 
    where T : class
{
    var likeness = from item in list
                   select item.AsSource()
                              .OfLikeness<T>();
    return likeness;
}
```

... and two lists can be then compared:

```
private static void AssertExpectedAndActualListsHaveSameElements<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> actual,
    IEnumerable<Likeness<T, T>> expected)
    where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<Object> expectedAsObjects = expected;
    IEnumerable<Object> actualAsObjects = actual;

    bool sequencesEqual = expectedAsObjects.SequenceEqual(actualAsObjects);
    Assert.IsTrue(sequencesEqual, "Expected and actual lists elements differ.");
}
```

Question: is it possible to add Witout() for unknown amount of properties dynamically?
Something like WitoutAll() would do:

```
private static IEnumerable<Likeness<T, T>> CreateLikenessOfListItemsWithou<T, TProperty>(
    IEnumerable<T> list, 
    IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, TProperty>>> propertyPickers)
    where T : class
    where TProperty : class
{

    var likeness = from item in list
                   select item.AsSource()
                              .OfLikeness<T>()
                              .WithoutAll(propertyPickers); // <= for all pickers
    return likeness;
}
```

Comment: Currently, Likeness doesn't have such a feature, so you may have to resort to Reflection if you need something like that...